# Only first pass trough logic gates raising a flag, second deactivating it, others doing nothing

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression, bitarray

I would like to model a `bitarray` of flags, where only the first pass through a logical expression sets a flag, but the second pass (computing with the previous state) deactivates the flag and all other passes do nothing to it.

I cannot think of a right combo of the previous state, the right logical expression and a second input `(0/1)`.

```
bitarray[i] = operand(bitarray[i], value_making_a_change)
```

- Desired value **after the 1. pass**: `bitarray[i] = boolean_value`.
- Desired value **after the second pass**: `bitarrayp[i] = neg(boolean_value)`.
- Desired value **after every consequential pass**: `bitarrayp[i] = neg(boolean_value)`.

I think I could just test the value, but my `bitarray` could get quite large, so I would not want to do that for every index. Is there a standard logic gate/expression I could use?

I tried just using `XOR(old_value, 1)`, but that changes the value back and forth:

```
value = 0
value = XOR(value, 1) = XOR(0, 1) = 1
value = XOR(value, 1) = XOR(1, 1) = 0
value = XOR(value, 1) = XOR(0, 1) = 1
...
```

Comment: Can you explain "flag and all other passes do nothing to it."? Maybe adding an example with values in question will be helpful

Comment: @Swanand An example is in the question. I would like to find a boolean function, that sets a flag for the first pass, removes it in the second and then it remains removed. I tried XORing the old value with 1, but that changes it back and forth: 1st pass 0^1->1, 2nd pass 1^1->0, 3rd pass 0^1->1, 4th pass 1^1->0. I would like it to stay the same after the second pass using logical operands and boolean values.

Comment: And are you modelling this in C? or Matlab?

Comment: Java:) Does that make a difference?